# How to reset stateful component after AJAX has completed?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a stateful component that switches between displaying data and editing the same data in a form. Saving the data fires an action `REQUEST_UPDATE` which calls an API through AJAX and dispatches `RECEIVE_UPDATE` when the update was successful (using redux-thunk).

**Upon successful saving, I want the stateful component to change its `editing` state** back to `false`, making the form disappear.

One idea is to reset the `editing` state in `componentWillReceiveProps`, comparing the data passed through props. This seems a bit clumsy though as the `editing` state should only change as a result of the `RECEIVE_UPDATE` action. Is there an elegant way to achieve this?

**Update: more details**

```
// component, connected to the reducer
state: { editing: true }
props: { name, address, city }

// reducer data
{ name: "Toby", address: "123 Test Ave", city: "NYC" }
```

Comment: Setting `editing = false` in the reducer of `RECEIVE_UPDATE` should do the job.

Comment: Clarification: `editing` is a state variable of the component, not inside the reducer

Comment: If this isn't what you're looking for, I'll delete the answer.

Answer (score 4):

A common pattern for this is to have `REQUEST_UPDATE` set a value in the redux store such as `isUpdating: true`.  Then `RECEIVE_UPDATE` sets it back to false. Your stateful component can then connect to the `isUpdating` prop and will receive it when it changes.